# Faulty behavior when detecting an elements height

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to detect the height of the html element defined below. To do this I am using Jquery (example below). I would expect the variable x above 40 pixels, however it is always set to 10. I found that if I change the padding on the element say from 5 pixels to 6. the value x is set to becomes 12. which indicates only the padding is being returned. Which is not the behavior I want to see, I have tried the other variations of doing this via jquery with even more confusing results.

Can anyone spot an reason why this is the case. Thanks :)

```
<section id=\"sophiaHeader\">Show Me Products I\'ll Like<p id=\"disclaimer\" style=\"top:' + disclaimerYPosition +'; right:'+ disclaimerXPosition +' ;\"><img id="sophiaLogo" src="https://d33f10u0pfpplc.cloudfront.net/perun/v1/images/bookmarklet/favicon.ico"></p> </section>
```

css bound to this element is:

```
#sophiaHeader { 
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
background-color: #4c3290;
border: 0 none;
margin: 0;  
cursor: pointer;
color: white;
font-size: 15px;    
padding: 5px;
text-align: center; 
text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Jquery

```
var x = jQuery('#sophiaHeader').outerHeight();
```

NOTE: the code is appended to a container like so. were the code above = sophiaCustomHeaderHTML

```
jQuery("#widget-container").append(sophiaCustomHeaderHTML)
```

Comment: Can you replicate your issue in a fiddle?

Comment: Good idea, I will attempt to now. thanks

Comment: Probably a timing issue, show us the code of how you are inserting the section element

Comment: Or maybe just try .height() and add your padding manually. I sometimes had issues with outerHeight

Comment: fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/FRN89/

Comment: If i use .height() x then returns as 0

Comment: I was messing around a bit, and was getting the correct value for x when manually setting the height

Comment: Hi Guys. 

The problem was the container it was being appended to was set to

    display:none 

in the css

Therefore the height was being returned as zero.

Hopefully this might help someone else with the same issue.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the container it was being appended to was set to

```
display:none
```

Therefore the height was being returned as zero.

Hopefully this might help other people :)